# SQL query returning Subquery returned more than 1 value error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query. Please have a look on that first

```
select 
    X.ITEMCODE, X.[ITEM_DESCRIPTION], X.[OPENING_BALANCE],   
    X.[SALES], X.[TOTAL_REJECTS], x.[REJECTION_DISEASES]
    (X.[SALES] - X.[TOTAL_REJECTS]) as [PRODUCTION_TOTAL], 
    X. [DOCDATE],
    (X.[OPENING_BALANCE] + (X.[SALES]-X.[TOTAL_REJECTS])) AS [CLOSING_BALANCE]
from
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         T0.ItemCode AS ITEMCODE, T0.ItemName AS [ITEM_DESCRIPTION],
         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(T1.OnHand)  
                 FROM OITW T1 
                 WHERE T1.WhsCode = 'FGS' 
                   AND T1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode), 0) AS [OPENING_BALANCE],
         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(T1.[Quantity]) 
                 FROM INV1 T1 
                 WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[ItemCode]), 0) AS [SALES] , 
         (SELECT T1.[DocDate] FROM INV1 T1 
          WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[ItemCode]) AS [DOCDATE],
         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(cast(T1.[Quantity] as int))  
                 FROM IGE1 T1 
                 WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[ItemCode]), 0) AS [TOTAL_REJECTS],
         ISNULL((SELECT T1.[U_RejectionOthers]   
                 FROM IGE1 T1 
                 WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[ItemCode]), 0) AS [REJECTION_DISEASES]
    from 
        OITM T0 
    where 
        T0.[ItmsGrpCod] in ('104', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '129', '130', '134', '135', '136', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145')) X
WHERE 
    X.[OPENING_BALANCE] > 0 OR X.[TOTAL_REJECTS] > 0  OR X.[SALES] > 0
```

In this code when I tried to add `X.[DOCDATE]` and `x.[REJECTION_DISEASES]` in the main select statement then I get the following error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Please experts help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect below `sub-query` returns more than one row for given condition in `where` clause

```
Isnull((SELECT T1.[u_rejectionothers] 
        FROM   ige1 T1 
        WHERE  T0.[itemcode] = T1.[itemcode]), 0) AS[REJECTION_DISEASES]
```

Either you need to fix the `where` clause to return one row or `TOP` plus `Order by` to return one row

Fixing `where` clause. Put the all the conditions in where clause through which you can identify a unique line in `ige1` table

```
Isnull((SELECT T1.[u_rejectionothers] 
        FROM   ige1 T1 
        WHERE  T0.[itemcode] = T1.[itemcode]
          AND  T1.somecol  = 'XXX'), 0) AS[ REJECTION_DISEASES]
```

Adding `TOP` plus `Order by` in `sub-query`

```
Isnull((SELECT TOP 1 T1.[u_rejectionothers] 
        FROM   ige1 T1 
        WHERE  T0.[itemcode] = T1.[itemcode]
        Order by somecol), 0) AS [REJECTION_DISEASES]
```

Comment: why you add here top 1 ?  @VR46

Comment: `Top` to avoid sub-query returning more than one row error. Also i have mentioned another way to do it which is more meaningful